# "boh" in English?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, exclamations

Quando parlo in inglese (o tedesco), mi capita comunque spesso di infilarci dei "boh", spesso lasciando i miei interlocutori internazionali un po´ interdetti. Che voi sappiate, esiste una **interiezione** (massimo 1-2 parole) che renda l´equivalente di "boh" in altre lingue?

(Should I also translate the question into English? This is my first question here)

Grazie.

Comment: ***Dunno*** può essere un modo di tradurre   ***boh*** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dunno.

Comment: Actually this is a site about Italian language: we do our best to explain to you, even in English, the meaning and nuances of Italian words and phrases rather than the opposite. Our sister site http://english.stackexchange.com could also help in that respect.

Comment: Confermo: qui non è previsto che si chieda come si dice qualcosa in inglese o altre lingue.

Comment: Piffy è comunque il benvenuto e può dare il suo contributo per la lingua Italiana.

Comment: Grazie, ero un po' incerto se il sito adatto era questo o altri. Ma dato che pensavo anche ad altre lingue (tedesco, francese, ecc.) mi semprava che il punto comune fosse qui. 
Cercherò di dare il mio contributo da madrelingua, anche se ho visto che il livello degli interventi è molto elevato! I'm a CS teacher, not a linguist!

Comment: Chiedo scusa: ho risposto di getto, senza interrogarmi sulla pertinenza della domanda.

Comment: "ch'sais pas" in francese.
Benvenuto!

Comment: Io sto seguendo l'approccio opposto, sto riuscendo a insegnare Boh! a tutti quelli che mi sono vicino!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Boh* è un’interiezione propria, senza un significato proprio. Se si cerca un equivalente inglese anche sotto l’aspetto grammaticale, un’interiezione inglese di uguale significato, si cerca invano.

Si può dire però *dunno*, grafia che ricalca la pronuncia trascurata, rilassata di «(I) don’t know» (si veda in proposito la voce «[Boh](http://oxfordparavia.it/lemmaIta4057)» del dizionario bilingue *Oxford Paravia*).